# How come when I'm sculpting with this subdivided sphere, it doesn't pick up vertices outside or inside of these four dots?

Tags: modeling, vertices, sculpting

I'm following along with a youtube tutorial on how to sculpt a basemesh, here's the link if it helps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ6wUtR6cWo

I'm near 5:30 where he begins sculpting, but I've run into a problem; I can't select vertices within or outside of the four circled in the image below and I'm not sure why.
[image]

I've re-watched it a billion times, maybe it's to do with it being in blender 2.8 in the tutorial when I'm using 2.92? Any help would be appreciated, this is my third day modeling and first day sculpting.

Comment: Did you remember to apply the subdivision modifier in Object mode before you switched to the sculpting view? If you don't do that first it will look the same but you won't be able to sculpt it because the extra vertices haven't been created by the modifier. In 2.92 you either use the dropdown in the modifier to find the Apply setting or hover the cursor ver the modifier and use CTRL-A (as you can in 2.8).

Comment: Yes I did Ctrl + 2 and then Ctrl + A and clicked scale before entering sculpture. I think that's what your were asking about. I Started with a cube however, not a UV Sphere, not sure if that was obvious or not but probably should've mentioned it.

Comment: Yes it was. All I can say is that it works fine here in 2.92.